# Splash screen background color invalid attribute

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to change background color of splash screen in my windows store app, but when I paste `#FF93744F` in `package.appxmanifest`>`Visual Assets`>`Splash Screen`>`Background color` I get `attribute is invalid` can anyone tell me why and how can I enter that specyfic color as background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#FF93744F` is invalid because this field accept RGB color value without alpha - `#93744F`.